# Gallery3 > REST API > what URL to POST new photo

Tags: php, rest, api, post, gallery

I am attempting to use the Gallery3 REST API to upload an image.  According to the limited API documentation I should be posting new items to this endpoint `/index.php/rest/item/1`.

Documentation: http://codex.galleryproject.org/Gallery3:API:REST#Example_create_request

Can anyone confirm this because I keep getting `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

I am able to connect to the gallery, get member albums, and get photos.  I just can't seem to upload new photos to the gallery.

Comment: Did you `urlencode` your `json_encode($data)`  ?

Comment: Yes I did.  I was actually able to create a new album by posting to that URL from Postman, so that does seem to be the correct URL.  However, I get errors when doing it from PHP.  It has something to do with `stream_context_create()` and/or `file_get_contents()`.  I'm going to try cURL instead.

Comment: Then `allow_url_fopen` might be set to off try enabling it in php.ini

Comment: I checked.  Its on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct URL.  I was able to create an album by posting to that URL using Postman.  My error seems to have something to do with my PHP ... specifically something to do with `stream_context_create()` and/or `file_get_contents()`.